# Insert statement with where clause

Tags: mysql, for-loop, insert, where-clause

I had a table with unique Date_t1 date type field, but in Table description field is not mentioned as unique, now while inserting new row I need to validate if date exist or not, If already exist I should not allow to make changes on that row, neither a new row needs to be created, Any idea how to resolve this problem in efficient way,

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a UNIQUE index.. you can use this to your advantage with `INSERT IGNORE`

Consider the following:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table SET id = 100 ...`

Assuming `id` is the `UNIQUE` column here... MySQL will throw an error if you try to re-insert this. But since you're using `IGNORE`, the error is silently thrown away.